# Error when running apt-get update from my own apt-mirror

Tags: apt, server, updates, repository

I recently setup a server for apt-mirror with Ubuntu 20.04 server in our network. The mirror-sync itself works without any error.
After that i changed the Repository path on one of my Ubuntu 20.04 test servers in `/etc/apt/sources.list` .
When running apt-get update on the test-server i receive the following errors:

```
Err:7 http://repository.XXX.XXXXX.XX/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  404  Not Found [IP: XXX.XX.XX.XX 80]
Err:19 http://repository.XXX.XXXXX.XX/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  404  Not Found [IP: XXX.XX.XX.XX 80]
Err:27 http://repository.XXX.XXXXX.XX/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  404  Not Found [IP: XX.XX.XX.XX 80]
Ign:16 http://repository.XXX.XXXXX.XX/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
E: Failed to fetch http://repository.XXX.XXXXX.XX/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64  404  Not Found [IP: XX.XX.XX.XX 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://repository.XXX.XXXXX.XX/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/cnf/Commands-amd64  404 Not Found [IP: XX.XX.XX.XX 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://repository.XXX.XXXXX.XX/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/cnf/Commands-amd64  404 Not Found [IP: XX.XX.XX.XX 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

i already tried running `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` on the server receiving update and deleting all mirror-files and running apt-mirror on the repo-server again.

I'm relative new to linux and i couldn' find any existing posts about this.
thanks for helping

Image of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

[image]

Comment: Please list output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` in your question - it most likely has errors. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: i added the output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list as a link ( i cant post more than 10 links)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists Did not answer my question. i only have one repository configured, which is hosted by myself on another server

Comment: Where? Can't you edit the post?

Comment: Remove or comment out the line you added to `/etc/apt/sources.list` - it probably gives the error.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWuyU.png

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can contact your server, but it doesn't get the response it should:

> The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code
> indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server,
> but the server could not find what was requested.

So there is something wrong with the configuration of the `apt` mirror server that gives a 404 error. Unfortunately, you haven't provided any clues to what this could be.